# Rendering with painters and HG2 leads to black background of plot after printing

Tags: matlab, matlab-hg2

If I print a figure in MATLAB the background of the plot gets rendered black instead of white, like this:

[image: Image with wrong background]

(But in the figure window of MATLAB it is white as it is supposed to be)
This is the code similar to the one used to print the figure(but will run copy-paste):

```
figure;
set(0,'DefaultAxesFontSize',13)
set(0,'DefaultTextFontSize',13)
set(gcf, 'Renderer', 'painters');
y = 1:100;
plot(y)
xlabel('Some X', 'FontSize', 14)
ylabel('Some Y', 'FontSize', 14)
title('Example', 'FontSize', 15)
legend('some function')
print(gcf,'test1.pdf','-dpdf')
```

If I add the following line, however, it works (but there a slight grey background in the areas around the plot, of course)

```
set(gcf, 'color', [0.99 0.99 0.99])
```

My MATLAB version is R2013a (8.1.0.604)

**edit:**
`set(gcf, 'InvertHardCopy', 'off');` does not resolve the issue.

**edit2:**
The problem seams to be caused by the HG2-Update.

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/changing-a-figures-settings.html#f3-99733 Try `InvertHardCopy` (haven't tested)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm also using the **HG2-Update** hack for the sake of beauty. Returning to **HG1** is no option for me. Well, I don't have any problems with it, except one: printing directly to **.pdf**. That's what you're trying to do also. This functionality is still totally screwed up.

The solution: Save with the plot with `-dsvg` as vector graphic, open the file in **Inkscape** and save again as pdf with the **Export area is drawing** checkmark set.

I actually hoped to find a way to script this procedure, without success. So you have to do it manually or wait for the final release of HG2.

Comment: Sounds like an acceptable workaround. By the way, `export_fig` is aimed at supporting HG2. Unfortunately having legends on the figure is breaking it at the moment. I posted an issue here: https://github.com/ojwoodford/export_fig/issues/4 Fixing this would render the workaround unnecessary.

Comment: @rob As I would be the developer of that function I would wait until the final release of HG2. Nobody knows what they will change until then. It's quite easy to write a similar function by yourself, but with full control about everything. And the vector-graphic-export issue one needs to workaround as mentioned.

Comment: If you should be able to find a scripted procedure to save figures as pdf with HG2, please let me know :)

Comment: @rob Have a look at my [**Question & Answer here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25229045/exporting-vector-graphics-as-pdf-using-hg2-update-is-not-working-properly/25229055#25229055)!

Answer (score 1):

The copy-paste code actually works fine on my version (R2013a as well), but to ensure the background color stays what it appears to be like after print, use this:

```
set(gcf, 'InvertHardCopy', 'off');
```

You can look at the example in the matlab docs [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/changing-a-figures-settings.html?s_tid=doc_12b#f3-99733) under Setting the Background Color.

Thus, to get a different background color for your plot, use:

```
set(gcf, 'color', 'blue');
set(gcf, 'InvertHardCopy', 'off');
print(gcf,'test1.pdf','-dpdf')
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, I already tried `InvertHardCopy`. Strange that it works for you, so this might either be a OSX issue (what OS do you use?) or something else related to my installation.

Comment: Strange--I'm on Windows 7.

Comment: @rob Maybe try the `export_fig` function in the MATLAB FEX and see if that works? http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-export-fig

Comment: `export_fig` did not work, BUT there was an interesting error: `Error using hg2.Group/get`. I found out that HG2 was enabled (which is not yet officially supported). Going back to HG1 solved the issue for me