# Exporting figures as vector graphics in .pdf-format using HG2-Update and 'painters' renderer is not working properly

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, matlab-hg2

I'm using the still undocumented [**HG2-Update**](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/hg2-update) to create my MATLAB plots, because they just look that much nicer.

[image][image]
(Source: Yair Altman)

Actually, using the current version **Release 2013b** it works quite nicely and there are not much issues. Except one wants to export the figures as vector graphics (renderer: `'-painters'`), especially as **pdf**.

I use the commands:

```
saveas(gcf,'test.pdf','pdf')
```

or

```
print(gcf,'test.pdf','-dpdf')
```

There are [**rendering issues**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25185260/rendering-with-painters-and-hg2-leads-to-black-background-of-plot-after-printing/25202008#25202008), the print does not contain the whole figure and some parts are cropped or non-default fonts are not recognized.

But I'd really like to stay with **HG2** and I'd still like to use **vector graphics**. Is there any solution or workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exporting vector graphics using the yet not official [**HG2-Update**](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/hg2-update) is quite an issue. The **.pdf**-export is still totally screwed up.
What is working fine is the **.svg**-export, apart from that the boundary box is not set properly.

The long workaround would be:
Save the plot with `'-dsvg'` (`print`-command) or `'svg'` (`saveas`-command) as vector graphic, open the file in the open source application [**Inkscape**](http://www.inkscape.org/en/) and save again as **.pdf** with the **Export area is drawing** checkmark set.

Quite complicated, so I found a way to do it **via command-line directly from Matlab** (Inkscape still required!):

```
filename = 'test';
inkscapepath = '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Inkscape\inkscape.exe"';

%// save as .svg
saveas(gcf,filename,'svg')
%// open and save with "export-area-drawing" set via command line
system( [inkscapepath ' ' filename ...
         '.svg --export-area-drawing --export-pdf=' filename '.pdf'])
```

It takes some time, but works without any known issues for now.

Additionally delete the svg-File afterwards:

```
delete([filename '.svg'])
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and used the workaround from thewaywewalk. Now I discovered the MATLAB  function "hgexport" works under HG2 (in R2014a).

An issue still was the paper size. I want to use the same size for all graphs with as little white frame as possible. Here you have to set two sizes:

The papersize is set with `set(gcf,'PaperSize',[width height])` and the size of your chart is set through export styles. These are set in "Export Setup" or command line:

```
exp_style=hgexport('readstyle','default');
exp_style.Width = 'width';
exp_style.Height = 'height';
exp_style.Renderer = 'painters';
```

Now you can export your pdf:

```
hgexport(gcf,'pdfname',exp_style,'Format','pdf');
```

PS: In HG2 you may also use Latex for tick labels:

```
set(gca,'TickLabelInterpreter','latex');
```