# Can not display a png image file which is modified from a svg file in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, svg, imshow

I tried this code to modify svg image to png

```
    filename = 'hello';
    inkscapepath = '"my inkscape path"';
    system( [inkscapepath ' ' filename ...
             '.svg --export-area-drawing --export-png=' filename '.png'])
```

It will create a hello.png file.
If I open it with windows picture viewer it is looking fine.The same content is present.
 svg image is in png form but resolution changed from 100x100px to 60x8.

But to view it in MATLAB if use

```
    imshow('hello.png')
```

A fully black image is coming as output figure.
the image matrix contains all the entries equal to 0

Comment: What does `imfinfo('hello.png')` return?

Comment: Filename:'hello.png'
FileModDate:
FileSize:764
Format:'png'
FormatVersion:[]
Width:60
Height:8
BitDepth:24
ColorType:'truecolor'
FormatSignature:[13780787113102610]
Colormap:[]
Histogram:[]
InterlaceType:'none'
Transparency:'alpha'
SimpleTransparencyData:[]
BackgroundColor:[]
RenderingIntent:[]
Chromaticities:[]
Gamma:[]
XResolution:3543
YResolution:3543
ResolutionUnit:'meter'
XOffset:[]
YOffset:[]
OffsetUnit:[]
SignificantBits:[8888]
ImageModTime:[]
Title:[]
Author:[]
Description:[]
Copyright:[]
CreationTime:[]
Software:'www.inkscape.org'
Disclaimer:[]
Warning[]
Source[]
Comment[]
OtherText[]

Comment: modified path and file date in previous comment to reduce text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is based on a guess that the file only contains a black image on a transparent background
Such as this one:

> [image: Original Image]  -it's in a spoiler to show transparency

With `imshow` Matlab replaces transparent pixels with black, to avoid this we can use `imread` to load in the image with additional options to set transparent pixels to white and then use `imshow`

```
 RGB = imread('hello.png', 'BackgroundColor', [1,1,1] );
 imshow(RGB);
```

**Figure from passing the filename to `imshow`**

[image: black background]

**Figure from setting transparent pixels to white**

[image]